# Waterproof method to block non-javascript users

Tags: javascript

Is there a waterproof method to block users that have disabled JavaScript in their browser?

If I do a check with cookies, a user can add a cookie manually.

I need this check because a JavaScript JQuery popupwindow should always be displayed, even when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Serve an empty page that loads all of its actual content with AJAX? But why on earth would you want to do this to your users?

Comment: Because I have a JavaScript popup, and people must read and confirm the things in it.

Comment: If a user cares about to disable Javascript they care enough to not use a site that forces them to turn it on...

Comment: @Jordy That doesn't sound a task suitable for Javascript at all. What's wrong with a click-through web page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `noscript` tag in your html with a redirect like this:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=no-js.html" />
</noscript>
```

This way, if a user has disabled javascript, then he/she will be redirected to the `no-js.html` page, which you can customise as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Use the no script tag

to display a huge div that will block the page, or trigger a redirect with
 ?

still it sounds like a hacky method, perhaps you should use the noscript tag to display a message that JS should be activated for the full experience and functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You could set certain elements, like a log-in perhaps, to `display: none` with CSS. With JavaScript, simply remove that style.

Or you can use [this.](http://www.rei.com/product/794729/grangers-xt-proofer-waterproof-spray)